# Visual Studio Load Tests Virtual Users Simulation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I'm currently working on writing a load testing application that takes advantage of Load Test using Visual Studio 2010. The load test will simulate 20 users on the same machine, and I need some data to be shared in-memory between all simulated users.

I was suprised I couldn't find documentation answering the following question:

What seperates each virtual user's running context from the other? Does each virtual user runs the tests in its own process? Maybe in its own app domain? Or just on its own thread?
I need to know because if each user is running tests in its own process then all the in-memory cache isn't shared and is created for each user instead of one time for all of them, which is bad for me.

Comment: Are you asking how the test harness works or how the app being tested perceives the test users?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer but could you elaborate on why you need memory shared between users ?

The tests should be as real as possible and in the real world the users won't be using each others data. Off course within your application there can be sharing of date but this is your application state and is independent of users.

If you need the shared data to drive the tests you should make the test's data driven [see this link](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2010/06/17/Web-Performance-Testing-with-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx?Page=3)

If you need the data to synchronize the tests in some way or to keep counters or something I would suggest you redesigning your test strategy. Because the performance test's than would be influenced by your synchronization attempts.